# accessing JasperReport without passing username and password or anonymous user

Tags: jasperserver

I am using Jasper Report server and have created a report. I want the users to access my report just by clicking on a link. I don't want to pass the username and password to the link. Is there any way to do it?
or
how can I access the report with an anonymous user as after trying it with an anonymous role, it says that I don't have access to it? Any help regarding this would be really appreciated.
here is my link which I am trying:

```
http://my_ipjasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2FsampleDire&reportUnit=%sampleDir%2FSampleReport&output=pdf&standAlone=true&j_username=anonymousUser&j_password=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you allowed anonymous access to the report? If not, you can do so as per the wiki article here - https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/allow-anonymous-access-reports.

Comment: I have get that part but a few requirements are changed. I want keep using the username and password schem but want to encrypt that part. is there any method for that?

Comment: You can encrypt passwords in URLs as detailed here - https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-security-guide/v780/encrypting-passwords-urls